# Dynamic picture loading with PHP and proxy cache?

Tags: php, image, caching, dynamic, proxy

I am a developer of [Wave Framework](http://waveframework.com/), a lightweight framework that includes a number of functionality that makes it easier to deploy API's and serve resources dynamically.

One of those features is on-demand image editing. For example, on my server I have this file:

http://www.waher.net/w/resources/images/logo.png

But in my HTML, I load my image from a URL like this:

http://www.waher.net/w/resources/images/160x160&logo.png

This '160x160&logo.png' file does not actually exist and the only file that exists is 'logo.png'. Every HTTP request is routed to PHP and parameters in the file URL are parsed in order to apply additional functionality, like picture resolution.

Why is this useful? If my system has a large number of user avatars and my design changes, I can easily change the avatar picture URL's and everything works as expected. I never have to regenerate all the avatars of all my users, especially of those users that do not exist in my system anymore and just waste resources.

But here's my problem, if I want to implement Nginx to serve static files on my server, my system does not work. This is because Nginx will attempt to load static files itself and throws a 404 Not Found message if picture was not found. I assume that the same is true with Apache and Squid.

One of my clients specifically requested that they wish to serve images and resources through Nginx instead, but they would still like the dynamic images for the ease of development and design.

Is it possible to tell Nginx or Squid to send the request to PHP, if the image file itself is not found, get the 'dynamic' image from PHP and then send it to a user through Nginx? And at the same time always serving it from Nginx cache in any subsequent request to the same file?

I want to have the flexibility of dynamically loaded image files, but also have the speed of Nginx when serving image files. Is something like this possible? Do I need to set specific file headers in PHP that allow for this? (I already set cache and expire headers).

Thank you!

Comment: Sure, you just have to edit you nginx config. Search `.htaccess to nginx` and convert your htaccess file to a nginx config.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with .htaccess either. I am asking how to do it so that if Nginx does not find an image file then it sends the request to PHP that might return a response and if PHP returns a response then Nginx would cache that response and send it to anyone that requests the same (nonexistent) image file.